# PRAW how to catch a "received 401 HTTP response"

Tags: python, django, authentication, praw

I'm purposely trying to authenticate with wrong credentials to the reddit API using PRAW. I can see on my console that I'm getting "received 401 HTTP response" error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bob/Sites/django/myproj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/Users/bob/Sites/django/myproj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "/Users/bob/Sites/django/myproj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/Users/bob/Sites/django/myproj/src/blog/views.py", line 246, in syncMyPosts
    thisimage.remove_category = submission.removed_by_category
  File "/Users/bob/Sites/django/myproj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/praw/models/reddit/base.py", line 33, in __getattr__
    self._fetch()
  File "/Users/bob/Sites/django/myproj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/praw/models/reddit/submission.py", line 591, in _fetch
    data = self._fetch_data()
  File "/Users/bob/Sites/django/myproj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/praw/models/reddit/submission.py", line 588, in _fetch_data
    return self._reddit.request("GET", path, params)
  File "/Users/bob/Sites/django/myproj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/praw/reddit.py", line 726, in request
    return self._core.request(
  File "/Users/bob/Sites/django/myproj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/prawcore/sessions.py", line 329, in request
    return self._request_with_retries(
  File "/Users/bob/Sites/django/myproj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/prawcore/sessions.py", line 227, in _request_with_retries
    response, saved_exception = self._make_request(
  File "/Users/bob/Sites/django/myproj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/prawcore/sessions.py", line 185, in _make_request
    response = self._rate_limiter.call(
  File "/Users/bob/Sites/django/myproj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/prawcore/rate_limit.py", line 35, in call
    kwargs["headers"] = set_header_callback()
  File "/Users/bob/Sites/django/myproj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/prawcore/sessions.py", line 282, in _set_header_callback
    self._authorizer.refresh()
  File "/Users/bob/Sites/django/myproj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/prawcore/auth.py", line 349, in refresh
    self._request_token(
  File "/Users/bob/Sites/django/myproj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/prawcore/auth.py", line 149, in _request_token
    response = self._authenticator._post(url, **data)
  File "/Users/bob/Sites/django/myproj/lib/python3.8/site-packages/prawcore/auth.py", line 32, in _post
    raise ResponseException(response)
prawcore.exceptions.ResponseException: received 401 HTTP response
```

I would rather catch this error / exception and show a friendly message. Having a hard time understanding how to use the try catch exception.

Pretty new to python & Django.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you put more information on the code that is performing this login operation?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short sample that does what you want, using Python's [`try` and `except`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions). We import `ResponseException` because that is what we want to catch.

```py
import praw
from prawcore.exceptions import ResponseException

reddit = praw.Reddit(
    username="wrong_username",
    password="wrong password",
    client_id="bad client ID",
    client_secret="bad secret",
    user_agent="failing authentication",
)

try:
    print("Authenticated as {}".format(reddit.user.me()))
except ResponseException:
    print("Something went wrong during authentication")
```

We surround the code that will throw the exception (which is `reddit.user.me()` in this case) with the `try` and `except` blocks, so that we can specify the alternate behavior when an exception occurs.

Comment: Thank you @jarhill0, that worked and also appreciate the explanation.